# Compare value of a cell in DataFrame with value of a cell in a given row and the same column

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I have DataFrame of numbers and I would like to create new dataFrame with true and false values by comparing the value of a cell in `i` row and `j` column  with a value of a cell in '1' row and 'j' column. I do that using double for loop but maybe there is more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)
before asking Pandas questions. Specifically you should provide a sample dataframe and a specific question you

As for your question, suppose we have a df:

```
df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame().iloc[:5]
```

that looks like this

```
             A          B           C           D
G6p2JNeEet  -0.315007   0.519647    0.117529    0.532278
pQoojOAqyg  -1.611355   1.405858    -1.324369   0.573910
uFh3timL3x  -0.372210   1.394280    0.863960    0.162457
KfYIQCuya7  2.247528    -0.531482   -0.715472   2.523932
j5CM2VKjTH  1.784814    -0.459058   0.875925    1.955540
```

then you can compare for 'greater' condition, as an example, simply by

```
df1 = (df > df.iloc[0,:])
```

to obtain a boolean df:

```
            A       B       C       D
G6p2JNeEet  False   False   False   False
pQoojOAqyg  False   True    False   True
uFh3timL3x  False   True    True    False
KfYIQCuya7  True    False   False   True
j5CM2VKjTH  True    False   True    True
```